# Prove the following $(A \cup B)^C\subset (A \cap B) ^C $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Applying de morgan's law, I can't go on:

$(A \cup B)^c\subset (A \cap B) ^c \Longleftrightarrow A^c \cap B^c \subset A^c \cup B ^c   $

Comment: Show that in general $X \cap Y \subset X \cup Y$

Comment: @dani_s nice idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler than that. You have a rule that if $A\subset B$, then $B^C \subset A^C$.

Comment: Great idea, that works

Comment: 2 minutes for it

Answer (score 2):

Going back to the definitions and using the rules of predicate logic, it is easy to calculate this:
\begin{align}
& (A\cup B)^c \subseteq (A\cap B)^c \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in (A\cup B)^c \;\Rightarrow\; x \in (A\cap B)^c \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;^c\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in A\cup B \;\Rightarrow\; x \not\in A\cap B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: contraposition"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A\cap B \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A\cup B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$; definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x\in B \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \land x \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;P \land Q \;\Rightarrow P \lor Q\;$"} \\
& \text{true} \\
\end{align}
This is basically a more formal equivalent of element chasing.

Answer (score 1):

To prove $$(A\cup B)^C \subset (A\cap B)^C$$

it suffices to prove that if $x \in (A \cup B)^C$, then $x \in (A \cap B)^C$.  This approach is sometimes called "element chasing."